# ¿Manera correcta de usar distintas bases de datos en una plataforma web?

Tags: php

Estoy creando una plataforma web, a la cual podrán acceder distintas organizaciones de trabajadores.

Cuando un trabajador quiera ingresar a la plataforma, debe seleccionar a qué organización pertenece, luego poner su correo y contraseña, como se muestra en el siguiente form de ingreso:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El campo "Organización:" envía por `POST` el nombre de la base de datos a mi archivo validar.php, el cual se conecta a esa base de datos para luego iniciar la sesión y las variables de sesión.

El siguiente código hace lo recién descrito, pero para guiarse en el proceso solo miren la última variable de sesión que estoy iniciando:

**validar.php**

```
<?php 

try {
    $ndb = $_POST['dbname'];
    $params = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$ndb.';charset=utf8';
    $db = new PDO($params, 'root', '');
} catch (Exception $e) {
        die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

$email= $_POST['email'];
$contrasena= $_POST['contrasena'];
$select = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `empleados` WHERE email = :email AND clave = :contrasena");
$select->bindValue(':contrasena',$contrasena,PDO::PARAM_STR);       //PDO::PARAM_INT para enteros
$select->bindValue(':email',$email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$select->execute();

    if($select->rowCount()>0){
        $fila = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $_SESSION['rut'] = htmlentities($fila['rut']);                  
        $_SESSION['nombre1'] = htmlentities($fila['nombre1']);
        $_SESSION['nombre2'] = htmlentities($fila['nombre2']);
        $_SESSION['nombre3'] = htmlentities($fila['nombre3']);
        $_SESSION['apellido1'] = htmlentities($fila['apellido1']);
        $_SESSION['apellido2'] = htmlentities($fila['apellido2']);
        $_SESSION['edad'] = htmlentities($fila['edad']);
        $_SESSION['email'] = htmlentities($fila['email']);
        $_SESSION['rango'] = htmlentities($fila['rango']);
        $_SESSION['clave'] = htmlentities($fila['clave']);
        $_SESSION['database'] = $ndb;
        header("Location: principal.php");
    }
    else{
        echo '<script language = javascript>
        alert("email y/o Password incorrecta.");
        self.location = "index.html";
        </script>';
    }
?>
```

`$_SESSION['database']` contiene el nombre de la base de datos, entonces para todos mis archivos .php que contienen consultas sql, estoy usando el siguiente archivo para conectarme a la base de datos correcta:

**conex.php**

```
<?php
try {
    $ndb = $_SESSION['database'];
    $params = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$ndb.';charset=utf8';
    $db = new PDO($params, 'root', '');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
        die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

En todos esos archivos que contienen consultas sql, inicio/verifico sesión y luego incluyo este archivo "conex.php".

Esto funciona perfecto, sin errores, pero mi pregunta es:

- ¿Es esta una forma apropiada/correcta/eficiente para crear este tipo
  de plataformas multi-usuarios "multi-organizaciones"? ¿Por qué?
- ¿Es insegura? ¿Por qué?

Comment: Lo que me parece inapropiado es que tengas múltiples bases de datos para múltiples organizaciones. ¿Por qué no tener sólo campos de usuario y contraseña y que al loguearse verifique a que organización pertenece? ¿Y a qué te referís con "esta plataforma"?

Comment: distinguir la base de datos de una aplicacion? para eso podes usar la libreria curl

Comment: @Roberto Sepúlveda Bravo perdón pero tu excepción no funcionará nunca, ya que nunca será lanzada, échale un ojo.

Comment: @Maramal  Cada organización usará las mismas estructuras de las tablas pero con distintos datos, por eso tengo una base de datos para cada organización. Se me haría muy engorroso el manejo de los datos si mezclo todos los empleados de distintas organizaciones en la misma base de datos. Con "esta plataforma" me refiero a todo el conjunto de archivos y tecnologías que componen este proyecto, ¿por qué?

Comment: @nikomaster debería ser catch(PDOException $e) para que funcione? la verdad no manejo bien esa parte.

Comment: @RobertoSepúlvedaBravo Si, es parte del estándar, http://php.net/manual/es/class.pdoexception.php

Comment: @RobertoSepúlvedaBravo, sigo sin entender qué trabajo supone usar la misma base de datos para distintas organizaciones y con más razón si usarían los mismos datos. Me imagino que la estructura de la base de datos es modificable. Supondría una mejora para tu "plataforma" el hecho de centralizar las bases de datos.

Comment: @nikomaster gracias por la acotación, lo he editado.

Comment: @Maramal se usarán distintos datos, no los mismos. En todo caso estudiaré la forma de hacer lo que sugieres.

Comment: @RobertoSepúlvedaBravo Se supone que podrías utilizar una tabla "organizaciones" con estructura básica y otra "usuarios" que tenga "organizacion_id". Me parece lo más apropiado. No se recomienda utilizar  múltiples bases de datos para una misma aplicación. Tu pregunta es si es apropiado / correcto / eficiente, y no, no lo es. Pero poder hacerlo lo puedes hacer.

Comment: @Maramal cuando decís: _No se recomienda utilizar múltiples bases de datos para una misma aplicación_, Si bien podría ser complicado el mantenimiento, lo cierto es que podria tener problemas legales si las organizaciones comparten la misma base de datos. Además, no es una práctica **mala**, todo depende de lo que se necesite. De hecho, el CEO de StackOverflow lo utiliza para su sistema FogBugz.

Comment: @Maramal he trabajado en compañías en las que diferentes clientes usaban la misma aplicación pero por privacidad querían tener sus datos alojados en sus propios servidores. En esos casos teníamos que duplicar la base de datos en sus servidores y hacer algo parecido a lo que Roberto quiere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quiero explicarte algunas ventajas que veo en utilizar múltiples bases de datos para una misma aplicación.

1. Con una sola base de datos, tendrías que replicar por toda la base de datos el id de la organización. Pensá en las tablas Maestro, de configuración, o específicas para cada organización. Todas tendrían que tener su Id. (por ejemplo las que llenan los combos pueden ser opciones genéricas para cada organización)
2. Los clientes van a estar tranquilos de que su base de datos **está aislada de los de otras organizaciones**. Si hay información sensible que quieran resguardar, no les gustaría que otros la puedan ver.
3. Te permite **manejar los backup de manera independiente**. ¿Sino cómo harías? Con múltiples bases de datos, una organización puede tener su propio backup.
4. Permite que tu aplicación sea **escalable**. Podrías tener varias bases de datos en un servidor, y otras, de mayor tráfico, en otro.
5. Permite que tu aplicación sea más **segura**. Un error de código nunca expondrá los datos entre organizaciones. Y si una base de datos deja de funcionar por algún motivo, solo afectará al cliente específico.

La verdad es que podría seguir con más razones.

Si te interesa investigar un poco más, es interesante lo que explica el CEO de StackOverflow en este link https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W24218 del minuto 50:45 en adelante.

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso refuerza bastante lo que consideré al modelar las bases de datos. Justamente el punto 1 es mi principal razón de por qué tengo separadas las bases de datos de cada organización. El punto 4 se aplicará mucho en esta plataforma pues la cantidad de usuarios puede variar entre 5 y 300 aprox. por organización. Los puntos 2 y 5 no los tenía considerados pero es bueno saberlo. El punto 3 me recuerda que aún tengo pendiente esa parte. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Que bueno haber sido útil. Según veo vas bien encaminado. En sistemas distribuidos es común la práctica de tener multiples bases de datos. En mi  caso trabajo con WCF (arquitectura orientada a servicios), donde cada servicio es independiente y tiene su propia base de datos.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que yo haría para no exponer el nombre de las bases de datos (click derecho al formulario, inspeccionar elemento, revisar los name de los inputs, verás los nombres de las bases de datos de cada organización) es:

1. En lugar de que sea el nombre de la base de datos, que sea el nombre
   de la organización.
2. Al recibir el Post, primero validar la
       organización para decidir en qué base de datos pertenece el usuario.

De este modo ya queda "oculta" esa info. Entre menos info des sobre el funcionamiento interno de tu plataforma, mejor.

Para aplicar esto ya decides si lo quieres hacer en código (con una función o un método de una clase) o por medio de una tabla de configuración general, donde puedes colocar los nombres de las instituciones, el nombre de la DB que corresponden, y otras validaciones que quieras hacer, como el Ip desde el cual pueden acceder (de un país a otro, pues las Ip pueden diferenciarse por el país) y así evitas que un usuario externo (Alaska por ejemplo), intente acceder; y lo que después quieras agregar de modo que sea escalable.

Saludos.

Comment: No sé si entendí bien pero te refieres a que es mejor que el value que yo envíe por POST no contenga el nombre de la base de datos, sinó algún otro identificador/palabraclave que yo pueda distinguir en "validar.php" y según ese identificador/palabraclave asignar el nombre de la db? Eso me permitiría en cierta forma ocultar el nombre de la db.

Comment: Roberto es lo que digo. Imagina que un atacante descubra el nombre las bases de datos de tus clientes, es un dato a favor para él y en contra para ti y tus clientes.

Comment: Creo que ya lo he entendido, gracias.